# Why Won't Image Drawing Work In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sprites, coordinates, image

In my game at the beginning the first thing that you'll see is a campfire with this code:

```
 var campfire = new Image();
   campfire.onload = function () {
      ctx.drawImage(campfire, campfireX, campfireY);
 };
 campfire.src = "Sprites/Campfire.png";
```

However, it doesn't work, I put an

```
alert("All systems a-ok");
```

at the end and i get the alert so i don't understand why it's there. You can find the actual image file [here](https://www.pixilart.net/art/campfire-8c5a8a1067ab64e)   and the full code [here](https://github.com/ninja25538/Project). Sorry if I didn't format this well or something, I'm not very good at this =3

This may seem similar to an older question of mine in which I stated how to add a sprite **onto** the canvas, though in this case, I'm asking why the image doesn't **appear** on the canvas at all, even though there's no errors.

Comment: The reason you see your alert even if the image didn't load is because onload is a callback function. Put your alert inside that function. Use the dev tools in your browser to debug this. In this case prefer console.log('loaded'); over alert to avoid having to click the alert.

Answer (score 2):

You should use this (literally):

```
var campfire = new Image();
campfire.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(this, campfireX, campfireY);
};
campfire.src = "Sprites/Campfire.png";
```

Comment: I don't think it worked, when I tried it, the campfire still didn't show

Comment: That's weird, thought this would work. btw I know this is a little late but what about using an engine like [phaser](https://phaser.io). Or something even leaner like [Playgroundjs](http://playgroundjs.com)

Comment: It'll cost you a lot less heartache later to switch from your own engine to one that's already been battle tested. Trust me on this. I also had that "I'll use my own engine" pride. But ended up regretting it. Check out this link for some [really neat options and more resources.](http://html5devstarter.enclavegames.com/)

Comment: I would, but I'm too far into the game, if I stop now I'll have a couple months worth of work destroyed

Comment: You know I watched [this video](https://youtu.be/MF8AEtKXwEA?t=5m52s). In the video, 5k feet (game developer) decided to create their own engine, later on through development they found out that the game was having issues running on their custom engine (they refused to get a different engine and learnt the hard way)

Comment: All I'm trying to say is that you will work much faster with an engine by your side. And yes you will lose a couple of months worth of work. But trust me, it will take you only a couple of weeks to re-implement into the new engine. And when you are back on track you won't have to worry about all this engine work, just game design and implementation

Comment: Try moving your game to an engine like phaser in a week and see how you move through the features. Compare it to you working with your custom engine, and I'm certain those features were faster to implement in the engine (e.g. phaser) than in your custom engine.

Comment: And just in case you still don't believe me: http://www.gamesbrief.com/2013/08/confessions-of-a-failed-indie-developer/

Comment: Yeah, I probably should get an engine, though all I need to do is work out this bug and I'll be able to get through the rest of my game.

Comment: @TheGamerKing don't listen to me lol, if performance is a thing you care about, continue creating a game engine from scratch.